# Handling responses from server side in jQuery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a flaw in my code here and I am a little confused.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/contact/index/add/',
        data: $("#addContact").serialize(),
        success: function(data, status, xhttp) {
            var response = eval ("[" + data + "]");
            console.log(response.msg);
            if ( response.success ){
                console.log( response.msg );
            } else {
                console.log( response.msg );
            }
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });
```

What I am looking for is on the response to be able to access an array (encoded in JSON format), however I am getting 'undefined' on the console.log( response.msg ) line

If I console.log(response) it shows (in firebug) as:

> [Object { success=true, msg="test"}]

The request is sending back the following string:

> {"success":true,"msg":"test"}
>   Which is why I have to enclose the response in [ ] for the eval.

So what I am confused about is: how do I access the properties of said array.

Server side I have (php / zend framework)

> echo Zend_Json_Encoder::encode(array('success'=>true,'msg'=>'test')); exit;

What do I need to do to access the key/values of the array as in the line

```
if( response.success ) { // do something }
```

Do I need to modify server side or javascript side?

Comment: -- Update -- for starters, I corrected the dataType as json, not HTML, that fixed my [ ] issue.

Comment: -- 2nd Update -- please disregard this question, that was the entire problem, all I needed to do was set the correct dataType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the right `dataType`.  You should specify JSON as the returned data type:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: Yeah I wish there was a way to delete the question hah, I realized my error.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataType: "json"
```

And don't use **eval** to parse json. Use **jQuery.parseJSON**

Comment: Good to know, thank you... still learning :)  Was kind of concerned about the eval statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the square bracket with the regular ones is the eval statement `"(" +` ...